# send notification without using User model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

How can I send a notification without having to use the `User` model?

```
   public function SendSeguimiento(Request $request){


   $toUser = Clientes::find(2);


    

   Notification::send($toUser, new Seguimiento($toUser));
    // $pageName = 'widgets';
    return redirect()->route("clientes");
}
```

i try to send a notification to the email of the table `Clientes` in row 2

Database:
[image]

Clientes Model:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Clientes extends Model
{
    protected $table= 'clientes';
 
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'codigo', 'cliente', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

help pls

Comment: Could you please show all `Clientes` model?

Comment: yes, update my post

Answer (score -1):

Add `use Notifiable;` in your Clientes model

```
class Clientes extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

And then

```
$toUser->notify(new Seguimiento($toUser));
```

Answer (score -1):

Function `routeNotificationFor()` belongs to `Notification` trait. Simply, you need to use this trait in `Clientes` model.

```
...
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Clientes extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table= 'clientes';
    ...
}
```